# problema devolviendo respuesta desde php al front con ajax

Tags: php, ajax

estoy usando en un framework llamado sencha que trabaja con Ext.js. el código ya está hecho y estoy agregando una nueva funcion, pero no entiendo por que la respuesta de una petición ajax se ejecuta bien pero me viene vacía y me muestra este mensaje: `ext-all.js:21 Uncaught h {sourceClass: "Ext.JSON", sourceMethod: "decode", msg: "You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: ", message: "You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: "}`

la petición ajax la hago así:

```
       Ext.Ajax.request({
         url: PROCESS,
         method: 'POST',
         params: {permiso:'usuario', operacion:'prueba',id_funcionario: id_funcionario},
         success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            var respuesta=Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            console.log(respuesta.saludo);


         },

         failure: function(response, opts) {
             console.log('server-side failure with status code ');
         }
         });
```

y en el php tengo esto:

```
        switch($permiso){
        case "usuario":
        switch($operacion){
            case "prueba":
                $saludo='hola mrk';
                $output=array(
                    "success"=>true,
                    "info"=>$saludo
                );
                echo json_encode($saludo);
            break;
```

lo mas increíble es que practicamente estoy copiando y pegando algo que ya funciona pero con otro nombre, en la otra función si retorna vien el array que se retorna desde php, y en esta función no, y están iguales. alguien podría ayudarme a saber que sucede? tengo horas intentando resolver esto y nada que funciona. si mando a imprimir el objeto de la respuesta así:  `console.log(response)` me muestra esto:

````
request: {id: 39, headers: {…}, options: {…}, async: true}
requestId: 39
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
getResponseHeader: ƒ (l)
getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ ()
responseText: ""
responseXML: null
__proto__: Object ```
````

Comment: Tiene que haber otras cosas en tu PHP, quizá alguna otra salida por pantalla que hace que el JSON sea inválido. En estos casos tienes que controlar que desde el PHP no salga nada más que un JSON, con un mínimo espacio en blanco, carácter, `echo`, bloque HTML o lo que sea, ya dañaría el JSON.

Comment: el código lo ves bien ?

Comment: El mensaje de error es claro: *`You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String`*, significa que el JSON que está recibiendo desde el servidor es inválido. El código PHP que pones es sólo una parte. Si quieres pone el script PHP completo para revisarlo, porque como ya te dije, cualquier salida que haya en otra parte del PHP dañará el JSON, que es lo que de hecho debe estar ocurriendo.

Comment: O, quizá el error es por esto: `var respuesta=Ext.decode(response.responseText);` Comenta esa línea a ver qué pasa. Si el servidor responde con un JSON válido, `response` será un JSON, no necesitas decodificarlo.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo que sucede es que el código completo tiene 9.500 líneas, es extremadamente largo, y donde responde a la petición del ajax es en ese Case nada más.

Comment: Mira a ver si es por esta línea: `var respuesta=Ext.decode(response.responseText);` coméntala y mira a ver si funciona. Dinos también lo que muestra en la consola el `console.log(response);` que tienes.

Comment: Ya había probado sin eso, el error no lo muestra, pero cuándo hago el console.log(response), la propiedad responseText donde se supone que viene la respuesta está totalmente vacío. En mi pregunta mostré la respuesta del console.log(response) para que veas como se ve vacía.

Comment: Dado que tu PHP tiene 9500 líneas, te sugiero algo, dirige la petición a otro archivo PHP simple, donde sólo mandas esto: `$output=array(
                    "success"=>true,
                    "info"=>$saludo
                );
                echo json_encode($saludo);` y prueba si funciona. Si funciona, entonces tienes que revisar tus 9,500 líneas y controlar que no haya ninguna otra salida por pantallas, que no haya problemas de [BOM](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_de_orden_de_bytes) u otros relativos a la codificación.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103749/discussion-between-a-cedano-and-julianprog).

Comment: Me inclino a creer que el archivo php tiene problemas de BOM. Es típico de algunos editores de texto que guardan con una marca oculta.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en tu PHP estás intentando codificar un `string` en vez de un objeto o un array, supongo que querías responder el array completo y no sólo el texto de saludo:

```php
$output=array(
    "success"=>true,
    "info"=>$saludo
);
echo json_encode($output);
```

Algo adicional y con lo que lidié muchas veces en PHP son los Warnings y Errores, normalmente estos son siempre mostrados en pantalla cuando estamos en un ambiente de desarrollo, te sugiero que desactives al menos los Warnings ya que cualquier texto extra invalida por completo el JSON devuelto al navegador.